# Does my disk have SMART support? (got outputs)

Tags: hard-drive, smart, centos-7

I can't run SMART tests on disks of our servers and I couldn't make sure if they support this feature or not (CentOS 7.2).

**Short story**: We have a bunch of identical servers those assambled in a big data cluster. On one of them we are getting (aproximate average of two in a week) disks remounted as read-only.

I wanted to run SMART tests for those disks to find out underlying reason of this repeating problem but I am not able to run SMART tests. When I want just the information, it's fine:

```
[root@bigd08 ~]# smartctl -i /dev/sdj
smartctl 6.2 2017-02-27 r4394 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               HP
Product:              LOGICAL VOLUME
Revision:             4.52
User Capacity:        6,001,141,571,584 bytes [6.00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
Lowest aligned LBA:   0
Logical Unit id:      0x600508b1001c3738fab048c29ade60d9
Serial number:        PDNNK0BRH510G6
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Tue Dec 19 13:51:32 2017 EET
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported
```

Well, it says "Enabled". If I want to get full information:

```
[root@bigd08 ~]# smartctl --all -d scsi /dev/sdj -H
smartctl 6.2 2017-02-27 r4394 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               HP
Product:              LOGICAL VOLUME
Revision:             4.52
User Capacity:        6,001,141,571,584 bytes [6.00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
Lowest aligned LBA:   0
Logical Unit id:      0x600508b1001c3738fab048c29ade60d9
Serial number:        PDNNK0BRH510G6
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Tue Dec 19 10:47:10 2017 EET
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK

Error Counter logging not supported

Device does not support Self Test logging
```

or try test:

```
[root@bigd08 ~]# sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sdj1
smartctl 6.2 2017-02-27 r4394 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Short offline self test failed [unsupported scsi opcode]
```

I also tried running command selecting scsi as device type and in permissive mode but the output is the same. However, I did not try other possible device types:
ata, sat[,auto][,N][+TYPE], usbcypress[,X], usbjmicron[,p][,x][,N], usbsunplus, marvell, areca,N/E, 3ware,N, hpt,L/M/N, megaraid,N, cciss,N, auto, test

("test" option says they are scsi) Should I try them?
I tried getting some clues from below output:

```
root@bigd08 ~]# lspci -knn | grep 'RAID bus controller'
03:00.0 RAID bus controller [0104]: Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array Gen9 Controllers [103c:3239] (rev 01)
07:00.0 RAID bus controller [0104]: Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array Gen9 Controllers [103c:3239] (rev 01)
```

Nope, no clues I got.
I still want to believe they support SMART. They were purchased in the beginning of this year and isn't it 2017? They must have! Disks are HP brand as well as servers and RAID controllers but manufacturer is Seagate (ST6000NM0024).

I checked the product manual and seen some bits that indicate SMART support.
[screenshot from Seagate's manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGsbF.png)

https://www.seagate.com/www-content/product-content/enterprise-hdd-fam/enterprise-capacity-3-5-hdd/constellation-es-4/en-us/docs/100740544d.pdf

I don't know which bits it mentions though and how I can check them from command line. I assume they are the bits for which I see from the first smartctl command I run: "Available", "Enabled".

There are a lot of topics over internet which are similar to my case but most of them are about USB disks and left out.

I appreciate any help which I really need to get stable disks. I also accept your comments for why they may get read-only so often.

Comment: A HDD cannot lose it’s SMART support. Every HDD sold for the better part of nearly two decades support the standard.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound. I should better remove that part and stop helping omniscience :)